# Phpmyadmin CPU usage problems

Tags: phpmyadmin

My problem is that after using phpmyadmin about 1 hour it loads my cpu 100%. Phpmyadmin version 4.2.3, browser Google chrome last version. I found these processes using 'top' command in command line (ubuntu). I already tried to install new version of phpmyadmin and use another browser, no result. [image]

Processes with user=www-data and command=php. Someone know how to fix it? For now I'm just use command 'sudo killall php'
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try updating your phpmyadmin for more info: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php

Comment: Thanks Sailesh. Already did it before asking, not helped

Comment: Well, this issue can be caused by many reasons..
Try to figure out the logs. Edit your question by posting some logs that are generated in phpmyadmin

Comment: Added all details that I found. Tell please if I can provide something else. Thanks

Comment: I found something new. When I try to load one of my php project pages, it's loading cpu on 100% right away. So, the problem probably is not phpmyadmin, on last picture phpmyadmin monitor after loading this page, it creates a lot of connections and not removed it whenever

Comment: probably this is my problem (from phpmyadmin log) 
"Aborted clientsDocumentation 29  The number of connections that were aborted because the client died without closing the connection properly."

Comment: updated mysql, no result

Comment: It's a PHP bug where MySQL connections hang forever. Time to switch over to MySQL Workbench :)

Comment: I think it's because of number of core, seems phpmyadmin only read on core status